# multi-threading: does stack may overlap on physical memory

Tags: multithreading, memory, memory-management

I was told that the threads in a same process share the same physical memory space and the same virtual memory addresses, and each thread has its own function stack.

So saying that I have two threads `t1` and `t2`. If I'm right, the virtual memory addresses of the `t1` stack may be from `0x0000` to `0x0011` and the virtual memory addresses of the `t2` stack may be from `0x0100` to `0x0111`. In a word, their virtual memory addresses do not overlap.

So I have a question: How do they share the same physical memory? Do the `t1` and the `t2` may be located at the same piece of the physical memory? If this is possible, does it mean that the OS has to store the stack of the `t1` while the content switch to the `t2` happens?

Comment: This is done by paging mechanism which is typically a part of OS. That is unavailibility of a virtual memory page (block of 4096 bytes size) in physical memory when an address from its virtual range is requested by app, triggers the page swapping which implies loading the page from the file  into available physical memory slot. Unloading of a page if it isn't used for certain period of time happens the same way with using special file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. When we say `the same process share the same physical memory space and the same virtual memory addresses`, it actually means that the same process share the same physical memory space and the same virtual memory addresses, different processes have different physical memory space, saying the process A can not modify/access the process B’s physical memory space except shared memory. This protected separate memory sections for each process is achieved by the memory management unit (MMU).
2. When we say `threads share the same physical memory`. It means that all threads have the same address space, which means that they also share the same global variables. And every thread can access every memory address within the process' address space, the thread A can read, write, or even completely wipe out the thread B's stack.
3. Back to the question: `How do threads share the same physical memory?` For LinuxThreads, it uses (CLONE_VM | CLONE_FS | CLONE_FILES | CLONE_SIGHAND) parameters to call clone () to create "threads", which means shared memory, shared file system access count, Shared file descriptor table, and shared signal processing. http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/clone.2.html
   The difference between threads is the program counter (keeping track of which instruction to execute next), registers(holding its current working variables), thread stack(containing the execution history).